# Rank-one Matrix (first step in proving the SVD by induction on the rank of $A$)

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

This is an exercise and it is divided into steps. The first step says:

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ has rank 1. Let $u_1\in\mathbb{R}^m$ be a vector in $R(A)$ such that $\left \| u_1 \right \|_2=1$. Show that every column of $A$ is a multiple of $u_1$. Show that $A$ can be written in the form $A=\sigma_1u_1v_1^T$, where $v_1\in\mathbb{R}^m, \left \| v_1 \right \|_2=1$, and $\sigma_1>0$.

I'm getting confused because I keep wanting to use properties of SVD and I know I can't. I'm hoping a hint will put me on track.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ has rank 1, every time you take two columns that set will be linearly dependent, i.e. one column is a multiple of the other.

If $u_1\in R(A)$ is nonzero, we can write
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} u_1&\lambda_2 u_1&\cdots&\lambda_n u_1\end{bmatrix}
=u_1\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \lambda_2\\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}^T=u_1\cdot v_1^T.
$$
Now let $\sigma_1=\|u_1\|_2\,\|v_1\|_2$. Then
$$
A=\sigma_1\,\frac{u_1}{\|u_1\|_2}\,\left(\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|_2}\right)^T.
$$

Comment: @user726608: not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant that it my matrix A with rank 1 , can I use the regular method, where we calculate all the vectors of the orthogonal matrix? Since I did not succeed to do so.

Comment: I don't know what the "regular method" is. But if it is a method that produces the SVD, it should work with matrices of any rank.